# How to access SqlParameter array with name

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am creating `SqlParameter` Array and passing it to `StoredProcedure`. The output value will be set in StoredProcedures. How to access that value by parameter name?

```
 SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@test", Value = "test", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }};
```

This works

```
parameters[0].Value
```

How to make this to work?

```
parameters["@test"].Value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an array of SqlParameters, so it is going to remain ordinal as any array would work. You could probably use LINQ here (example shortly)

```
parameters.First(parameter => parameter.ParameterName == "@test")
```

Comment: hi thanks, +1 for `linq` and that works. Is there any other to do that?

Comment: @SSS not that I can think of atm. You could possibly encapsulate in an extension method, but I you wouldnt gain that much

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) method

> Returns the first element of a sequence.

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@test", Value = "test", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output } };
Console.WriteLine(parameters.First(parameter => parameter.ParameterName == "@test"));
```

Output will be;

```
@test
```

Comment: @SSS _Hmm_, I don't know any other way right now but if I find, I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, both answers works. But as he answered before you i am accepting his answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
enum ParamNames { ReportName, Description, MaxReportsAllowed, IncludeSignatures};

SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[32];
param[ReportName] = new SqlParameter("@ReportName", ReportName1.Text);
param[Description] = new SqlParameter("@Description", Description.Text);
```